# if still has need to log exception in callers when called method has log it?

Tags: java, logging

```
class 1:
public static void TypeOneException2TypeTwoException(TypeOneException exception)
                throws TypeTwoException {
            if (exception == null)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "TypeOneException shouldn't be null"); 
            LOG_SERVICE.debug(exception.getMessage(), exception);  //log it

            if (exception instanceof TypeTwoException)
                throw new TypeTwoException(
                        DavServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED,
                        exception.getMessage());


class 2:
public void callerOne(){
            try{

            }catch(TypeOneException exception){
                LOG_SERVICE.debug(exception.getMessage(), exception);  //is still need log it? any benifit?
                TypeOneException2TypeTwoException(exception)
            }

class 3:
public void callerTwo(){
            try{

            }catch(TypeOneException exception){
                LOG_SERVICE.debug(exception.getMessage(), exception); //is still need log it?
                TypeOneException2TypeTwoException(exception)
            }

class 4:
public void callerTwo(){
            try{

            }catch(TypeOneException exception){
                LOG_SERVICE.debug(exception.getMessage(), exception); //is still need log it?
                TypeOneException2TypeTwoException(exception)
            }
```

as titled. I have logged the error in class1. if has any need to log it in callers(class2,3,4)? if need, any benifits existed? Thanks in advance. Suppossed need, if the duplicate code existed?

Comment: Logging is for you.

Whether you need to log something is not based on any predetermined set of rules, but by your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with logging at multiple levels.  In many cases the lower level call which logs and throws the exception will be used in the context of a larger operation.  As such, it helps to add context to what was going on by also logging it at the higher level.

Keep in mind, logging is configurable, so ou can turn on/off logging for each logger (usually segregated by class level).

Comment: but I can track it throw stack traces (locate all caller and throw position). I can't catch your mean clearly. 3ks